# Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, homebrew, yarnpkg, linuxbrew

I'm running into:

> Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky

While trying to do:

`brew install yarn`

> Error: parent directory is world writable but not sticky
>   Please report this bug:
>    https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
>   /var/lib/jenkins/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:92:in `mktmpdir'

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like a permission problem. Mentioned in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/39170#issuecomment-97367623). Based on that fix is: `sudo chmod +t /tmp`

Comment: Thanks Arash. Could you tell me what the full path to /tmp is? I'm confused what it is referring to.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/39475). They are discussing the same problem. I think you need to do `sudo chmod +t /private/tmp`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a permission problem, When I am trying to install `brew install yarn --without-node`, Got this error,  on my Mac OSx Sierra

First, find out where is your `tmp` directory using `ls -ld /tmp` When I  ran this command, got the output in following way,

```
ls -ld /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jan 28  2017 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

which means tmp directory is using `private/tmp` So try giving the permission by using following command

```
sudo chmod +t /private/tmp
```

Comment: This was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error, but in my case the directory with bad permissions was `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`.

```
chmod +t ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew/Ruby wants to set sticky bit (+t) permission on /private/tmp folder. Set it explicitly using

```
sudo chmod +t /private/tmp
```

will solve the issue. Brew command should work fine after this.